# JavaFX disable Textfield when Combobox is set

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on my first JacaFX project and I want to disable a TextField when one or more ComboBoxes are set.

I can do this vice versa with the ComboBox, there is no problem with this code:

```
testCombobox.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isNotEmpty(testIdTextfield.textProperty())
            .or(Bindings.isNotEmpty(testTestTextfield.textProperty())
                    .or(Bindings.isNotEmpty(testTestTestTextfield.textProperty()))));
```

But how to do this with the TextField if the ComboBox is set?

Comment: testIdTextfield.disableProperty().bind(testCombobox.valueProperty().isEqualTo( ...conditionalvalue... ));

Comment: Hmm, I was sure I tried it this way but it seams that i did a mistake, it works, thank you

Comment: Or if you want to aggregate them, you can do it like you have did in the question: tf.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.equal(cbox.valueProperty(), ..value..)
           .or(Bindings.equal(cbox2.valueProperty(), new ..value..)));